# Install Magento 2 via command line: Getting Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054]

Tags: magento2, command-line

I am using Mac OS Catalina and I am trying to install Magento 2 via the command line and I am getting this error.

```
➜ php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://local.magento2.com --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2tutorial" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="Jonathan" --admin-lastname="Helvey" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --backend-frontname="admin"
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

In InstallCommand.php line 264:

  Parameter validation failed
```

Then I get these logs.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
setup:install [--amqp-host AMQP-HOST] [--amqp-port AMQP-PORT] [--amqp-user AMQP-USER] [--amqp-password AMQP-PASSWORD] [--amqp-virtualhost AMQP-VIRTUALHOST] [--amqp-ssl AMQP-SSL] [--amqp-ssl-options AMQP-SSL-OPTIONS] [--enable-debug-logging ENABLE-DEBUG-LOGGING] [--enable-syslog-logging ENABLE-SYSLOG-LOGGING] [--backend-frontname BACKEND-FRONTNAME] [--consumers-wait-for-messages CONSUMERS-WAIT-FOR-MESSAGES] [--key KEY] [--db-host DB-HOST] [--db-name DB-NAME] [--db-user DB-USER] [--db-engine DB-ENGINE] [--db-password DB-PASSWORD] [--db-prefix DB-PREFIX] [--db-model DB-MODEL] [--db-init-statements DB-INIT-STATEMENTS] [-s|--skip-db-validation] [--http-cache-hosts HTTP-CACHE-HOSTS] [--db-ssl-key DB-SSL-KEY] [--db-ssl-cert DB-SSL-CERT] [--db-ssl-ca DB-SSL-CA] [--db-ssl-verify] [--session-save SESSION-SAVE] [--session-save-redis-host SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-HOST] [--session-save-redis-port SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-PORT] [--session-save-redis-password SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-PASSWORD] [--session-save-redis-timeout SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-TIMEOUT] [--session-save-redis-persistent-id SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-PERSISTENT-ID] [--session-save-redis-db SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-DB] [--session-save-redis-compression-threshold SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-COMPRESSION-THRESHOLD] [--session-save-redis-compression-lib SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-COMPRESSION-LIB] [--session-save-redis-log-level SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-LOG-LEVEL] [--session-save-redis-max-concurrency SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-MAX-CONCURRENCY] [--session-save-redis-break-after-frontend SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BREAK-AFTER-FRONTEND] [--session-save-redis-break-after-adminhtml SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BREAK-AFTER-ADMINHTML] [--session-save-redis-first-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-FIRST-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-bot-first-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BOT-FIRST-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-bot-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BOT-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-disable-locking SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-DISABLE-LOCKING] [--session-save-redis-min-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-MIN-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-max-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-MAX-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-master SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-MASTER] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-servers SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-SERVERS] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-verify-master SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-VERIFY-MASTER] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-connect-retires SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-CONNECT-RETIRES] [--cache-backend CACHE-BACKEND] [--cache-backend-redis-server CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-SERVER] [--cache-backend-redis-db CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-DB] [--cache-backend-redis-port CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-PORT] [--cache-backend-redis-password CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-PASSWORD] [--cache-backend-redis-compress-data CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-COMPRESS-DATA] [--cache-backend-redis-compression-lib CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-COMPRESSION-LIB] [--cache-id-prefix CACHE-ID-PREFIX] [--page-cache PAGE-CACHE] [--page-cache-redis-server PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-SERVER] [--page-cache-redis-db PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-DB] [--page-cache-redis-port PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-PORT] [--page-cache-redis-password PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-PASSWORD] [--page-cache-redis-compress-data PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-COMPRESS-DATA] [--page-cache-redis-compression-lib PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-COMPRESSION-LIB] [--page-cache-id-prefix PAGE-CACHE-ID-PREFIX] [--lock-provider LOCK-PROVIDER] [--lock-db-prefix LOCK-DB-PREFIX] [--lock-zookeeper-host LOCK-ZOOKEEPER-HOST] [--lock-zookeeper-path LOCK-ZOOKEEPER-PATH] [--lock-file-path LOCK-FILE-PATH] [--base-url BASE-URL] [--language LANGUAGE] [--timezone TIMEZONE] [--currency CURRENCY] [--use-rewrites USE-REWRITES] [--use-secure USE-SECURE] [--base-url-secure BASE-URL-SECURE] [--use-secure-admin USE-SECURE-ADMIN] [--admin-use-security-key ADMIN-USE-SECURITY-KEY] [--admin-user [ADMIN-USER]] [--admin-password [ADMIN-PASSWORD]] [--admin-email [ADMIN-EMAIL]] [--admin-firstname [ADMIN-FIRSTNAME]] [--admin-lastname [ADMIN-LASTNAME]] [--cleanup-database] [--sales-order-increment-prefix SALES-ORDER-INCREMENT-PREFIX] [--use-sample-data] [--enable-modules [ENABLE-MODULES]] [--disable-modules [DISABLE-MODULES]] [--convert-old-scripts [CONVERT-OLD-SCRIPTS]] [-i|--interactive] [--safe-mode [SAFE-MODE]] [--data-restore [DATA-RESTORE]] [--dry-run [DRY-RUN]] [--magento-init-params MAGENTO-INIT-PARAMS]
```

I feel like I am so close on getting it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem the command line does not see any of your parameters. The amqp parameters I believe are not required. Therefore, it seems to be a red herrings to think these are missing.

I'd rather make sure your base-url parameter has quote though:

Also, you seem to have missed some parameters like database password, the below might work:

```
php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url="http://local.magento2.com" \
--base-url-secure="http://local.magento2.com" \
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-name="magento2tutorial" \
--db-user="root"
--db-password="tit0-%68839039it" \
--language="en_GB" \
--currency="GBP" \
--timezone="Europe/London" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--admin-firstname="Jonathan" 
--admin-lastname="Helvey"
--admin-email="user@example.com" 
--admin-user="admin"
--admin-password="admin123"
--backend-frontname="admin"
```

Comment: HI, Thank you for the help.  I tried doing something similar to yours and now it gives me this error: `  The "-u" option does not exist.`

Comment: This is What I put into console.  Something similar to yours but kept it to my Region
```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://local.magento2.com  --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="root" --db-password="tit0-%68839039it" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites=1 -use-secure=0 --admin-firstname="Jonathan" --admin-lastname="Helvey" --admin-email="user@example.com"  --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

Comment: You’re missing the quotes

Answer (score 0):

i solve this same issue on mysql 8

```
sudo mysql 

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'matin@123';
ALTER USER 'matin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'matin@123';
ALTER USER 'matin'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'matin@123';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Hope someone will help this